# knockout search-filter doesnt work

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I wrote my simple first example in knockout but I need a little help with two things. I searching information and examples of smiliar works but I don't found so I asking you.
I need to add simple search on my page where I can filter results by name and surname. My first question is how I can do that correct because my current solution show me all results; (extra question how I can filter my json by name and surname in one query)?
My second problem is with tab structure, is not working correct. Now when I click on li element I toggle results for this element to container and not hiding all current open results ([simple example what I want to do](http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/cGMTV/)); by the way I want to add style for active tab ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/wzwh2js1/)).
Probably my problem comming from external json but I'm not sure. Please chceck my code I'm open on better solution than main.

external JSON (example.json)

```
[
  {
    "index": 0,
    "name": [{
      "first": "Barlow",
      "last": "Moore"
    }]
  },
  {
    "index": 1,
    "name": [{
      "first": "Valeria",
      "last": "Meadows"
    }]
  },
  {
    "index": 2,
    "name": [{
      "first": "Constance",
      "last": "Singleton"
    }]
  },
  {
    "index": 3,
    "name": [{
      "first": "Wilder",
      "last": "Steele"
    }]
  }
]
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  });

  ko.bindingHandlers.slideVisible = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
      var value = valueAccessor();
      var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
      var duration = allBindings.get('fadeDuration') || 400;
      if (valueUnwrapped == true)
        setTimeout(function(){ $(element).fadeIn(duration); }, duration);
      else
        $(element).fadeOut(duration);
    }
  };

  /* show all data from json */
  function PersonInfo(data) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(data.name[0].first);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(data.name[0].last);
    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
      return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);

    this.showMoreInfo = ko.observable(false);
    this.toggleshowMoreInfo = function () {
      this.showMoreInfo(!this.showMoreInfo())
    }
  }

  function PersonInfoViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.personData = ko.observableArray([]);
    $.getJSON('example.json', function(allData) {
      var mappedPersonalData = $.map(allData, function(item) { 
        this.query = ko.observable('');
        var search = this.query().toLowerCase();
        if(item.name[0].first.toLowerCase().indexOf(search) >= 0) {

          return new PersonInfo(item) 
        }

      });
      self.personData(mappedPersonalData);
    });
  }

  var viewModel = new PersonInfoViewModel();

  <!-- template for presonal information -->
  <script type="text/html" id="person-template">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
      <p><span data-bind="text: fullName"></span></p>
    </div>
  </script>
```

HTML

```
<form action="#"> 
    <input placeholder="Search…" type="search" name="q" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="off"> 
  </form>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <ul class="name-list" data-bind="foreach: personData">
          <li data-bind="attr:{class: $index == 0 ? 'active' : ''}, click: toggleshowMoreInfo" role="button">
            <span class="full-name" data-bind="text: fullName"></span>
          </li>

          <div class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" data-bind="slideVisible: showMoreInfo, fadeDuration:600,template: {name: 'person-template'}"></div>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-8 hidden-xs" data-bind="foreach: personData">
        <div class="row" data-bind="slideVisible: showMoreInfo, fadeDuration:600,template: {name: 'person-template'}""></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. I used a computed observable to keep filtering the array of people to remove the ones that do not match.

```js
var data = [
  {
    "index": 0,
    "name": [{
      "first": "Barlow",
      "last": "Moore"
    }]
  },
  {
    "index": 1,
    "name": [{
      "first": "Valeria",
      "last": "Meadows"
    }]
  },
  {
    "index": 2,
    "name": [{
      "first": "Constance",
      "last": "Singleton"
    }]
  },
  {
    "index": 3,
    "name": [{
      "first": "Wilder",
      "last": "Steele"
    }]
  }
];

  var stringStartsWith = function (startsWith, string) {          
    string = string || "";
    if (startsWith.length > string.length)
        return false;
    return string.substring(0, startsWith.length) === startsWith;
  };

  ko.bindingHandlers.slideVisible = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
      var value = valueAccessor();
      var valueUnwrapped = ko.unwrap(value);
      var duration = allBindings.get('fadeDuration') || 400;
      if (valueUnwrapped == true)
        setTimeout(function(){ $(element).fadeIn(duration); }, duration);
      else
        $(element).fadeOut(duration);
    }
  };

  /* show all data from json */
  function PersonInfo(data) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(data.name[0].first);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(data.name[0].last);
    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
      return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);

    this.showMoreInfo = ko.observable(false);
    this.toggleshowMoreInfo = function () {
      this.showMoreInfo(!this.showMoreInfo())
    }
  }

  function PersonInfoViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.query = ko.observable('');
    self.mappedPersonalData = $.map(data, function(item) {  
      return new PersonInfo(item) 
    });
    self.filteredPeople = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.mappedPersonalData.filter(function (value) {
            if(self.query() === '' || self.query() === null){
               return true; //no query
            }
            if (stringStartsWith(self.query().toLowerCase(), value.firstName().toLowerCase()) || stringStartsWith(self.query().toLowerCase(), value.lastName().toLowerCase())){
               return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }); 
  }

  var viewModel = new PersonInfoViewModel();

  $(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<form action="#"> 
    <input placeholder="Search…" type="search" name="q" data-bind="value: query, valueUpdate: 'keyup'" autocomplete="off"> 
  </form>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        <ul class="name-list" data-bind="foreach: filteredPeople">
          <li data-bind="attr:{class: $index == 0 ? 'active' : ''}, click: toggleshowMoreInfo" role="button">
            <span class="full-name" data-bind="text: fullName"></span>
          </li>

          <div class="hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" data-bind="slideVisible: showMoreInfo, fadeDuration:600,template: {name: 'person-template'}"></div>
        </ul>
        
      </div>

      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8 col-lg-8 hidden-xs" data-bind="foreach: filteredPeople">
        <div class="row" data-bind="slideVisible: showMoreInfo, fadeDuration:600,template: {name: 'person-template'}"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 
                                                                                                                      
  <!-- template for presonal information -->
  <script type="text/html" id="person-template">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
      <p><span data-bind="text: fullName"></span></p>
    </div>
  </script>
```

Comment: As an aside, I found this knockout utils page to be very useful during development - http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html It allows you to keep jQuery out of knockout for the most part

Comment: Thank you for a help and link to article. This is nice example how to do search/filter correct by the way if you know answer on my second question in this post (about tab) I'll be great full.